# Swift - CRC8 calculation conversion from C++

Tags: c++, swift, crc

As part of a project I'm working on with pulling data from a bluetooth device, I was provided a CRC8 function from the manufacturer to use. I'm writing the application in Swift, but the function they provided is in C++.

**Below is the function they've provided in C++**

```
unsigned char xTable_CRC8[]={0x00, 0x07, 0x0E, 0x09, 0x1C, 0x1B, 0x12, 0x15, 0x38, 0x3F, 0x36, 0x31, 0x24, 0x23, 0x2A, 0x2D,0x70, 0x77, 0x7E, 0x79, 0x6C, 0x6B, 0x62, 0x65,0x48, 0x4F, 0x46, 0x41, 0x54, 0x53, 0x5A, 0x5D,0xE0, 0xE7, 0xEE, 0xE9, 0xFC, 0xFB, 0xF2, 0xF5,0xD8, 0xDF, 0xD6, 0xD1, 0xC4, 0xC3, 0xCA, 0xCD,0x90, 0x97, 0x9E, 0x99, 0x8C, 0x8B, 0x82, 0x85,0xA8, 0xAF, 0xA6, 0xA1, 0xB4, 0xB3, 0xBA, 0xBD,0xC7, 0xC0, 0xC9, 0xCE, 0xDB, 0xDC, 0xD5, 0xD2,0xFF, 0xF8, 0xF1, 0xF6, 0xE3, 0xE4, 0xED, 0xEA,0xB7, 0xB0, 0xB9, 0xBE, 0xAB, 0xAC, 0xA5, 0xA2,0x8F, 0x88, 0x81, 0x86, 0x93, 0x94, 0x9D, 0x9A,0x27, 0x20, 0x29, 0x2E, 0x3B, 0x3C, 0x35, 0x32,0x1F, 0x18, 0x11, 0x16, 0x03, 0x04, 0x0D, 0x0A,0x57, 0x50, 0x59, 0x5E, 0x4B, 0x4C, 0x45, 0x42,0x6F, 0x68, 0x61, 0x66, 0x73, 0x74, 0x7D, 0x7A,0x89, 0x8E, 0x87, 0x80, 0x95, 0x92, 0x9B, 0x9C,0xB1, 0xB6, 0xBF, 0xB8, 0xAD, 0xAA, 0xA3, 0xA4,0xF9, 0xFE, 0xF7, 0xF0, 0xE5, 0xE2, 0xEB, 0xEC,0xC1, 0xC6, 0xCF, 0xC8, 0xDD, 0xDA, 0xD3, 0xD4,0x69, 0x6E, 0x67, 0x60, 0x75, 0x72, 0x7B, 0x7C,0x51, 0x56, 0x5F, 0x58, 0x4D, 0x4A, 0x43, 0x44,0x19, 0x1E, 0x17, 0x10, 0x05, 0x02, 0x0B, 0x0C,0x21, 0x26, 0x2F, 0x28, 0x3D, 0x3A, 0x33, 0x34,0x4E, 0x49, 0x40, 0x47, 0x52, 0x55, 0x5C, 0x5B,0x76, 0x71, 0x78, 0x7F, 0x6A, 0x6D, 0x64, 0x63,0x3E, 0x39, 0x30, 0x37, 0x22, 0x25, 0x2C, 0x2B,0x06, 0x01, 0x08, 0x0F, 0x1A, 0x1D, 0x14, 0x13,0xAE, 0xA9, 0xA0, 0xA7, 0xB2, 0xB5, 0xBC, 0xBB,0x96, 0x91, 0x98, 0x9F, 0x8A, 0x8D, 0x84, 0x83,0xDE, 0xD9, 0xD0, 0xD7, 0xC2, 0xC5, 0xCC, 0xCB,0xE6, 0xE1, 0xE8, 0xEF, 0xFA, 0xFD, 0xF4, 0xF3 };

uint8_t CRC8(char *RP_ByteData, unsigned int Buffer_Size) {
 
 uint8_t x,R_CRC_Data;

 R_CRC_Data=0;

  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < Buffer_Size; i++) {
    x = R_CRC_Data ^ (*RP_ByteData);
    R_CRC_Data = xTable_CRC8[x];
    RP_ByteData++;
  }

 return R_CRC_Data;
}
```

**Here is my attempt at converting it so far:**

```
  func calCR8(buf : [UInt8]) -> UInt8 {
    let initialValue : UInt8 = UInt8.min;
    let Table_CRC8 : [UInt8] = [
        0x00, 0x07, 0x0E, 0x09, 0x1C, 0x1B, 0x12, 0x15,0x38, 0x3F, 0x36, 0x31, 0x24, 0x23, 0x2A, 0x2D,
        0x70, 0x77, 0x7E, 0x79, 0x6C, 0x6B, 0x62, 0x65,0x48, 0x4F, 0x46, 0x41, 0x54, 0x53, 0x5A, 0x5D,
        0xE0, 0xE7, 0xEE, 0xE9, 0xFC, 0xFB, 0xF2, 0xF5, 0xD8, 0xDF, 0xD6, 0xD1, 0xC4, 0xC3, 0xCA, 0xCD,
        0x90, 0x97, 0x9E, 0x99, 0x8C, 0x8B, 0x82, 0x85,0xA8, 0xAF, 0xA6, 0xA1, 0xB4, 0xB3, 0xBA, 0xBD,
        0xC7, 0xC0, 0xC9, 0xCE, 0xDB, 0xDC, 0xD5, 0xD2, 0xFF, 0xF8, 0xF1, 0xF6, 0xE3, 0xE4, 0xED, 0xEA,
        0xB7, 0xB0, 0xB9, 0xBE, 0xAB, 0xAC, 0xA5, 0xA2,0x8F, 0x88, 0x81, 0x86, 0x93, 0x94, 0x9D, 0x9A,
        0x27, 0x20, 0x29, 0x2E, 0x3B, 0x3C, 0x35, 0x32,0x1F, 0x18, 0x11, 0x16, 0x03, 0x04, 0x0D, 0x0A,
        0x57, 0x50, 0x59, 0x5E, 0x4B, 0x4C, 0x45, 0x42,0x6F, 0x68, 0x61, 0x66, 0x73, 0x74, 0x7D, 0x7A,
        0x89, 0x8E, 0x87, 0x80, 0x95, 0x92, 0x9B, 0x9C,0xB1, 0xB6, 0xBF, 0xB8, 0xAD, 0xAA, 0xA3, 0xA4,
        0xF9, 0xFE, 0xF7, 0xF0, 0xE5, 0xE2, 0xEB, 0xEC, 0xC1, 0xC6, 0xCF, 0xC8, 0xDD, 0xDA, 0xD3, 0xD4,
        0x69, 0x6E, 0x67, 0x60, 0x75, 0x72, 0x7B, 0x7C,0x51, 0x56, 0x5F, 0x58, 0x4D, 0x4A, 0x43, 0x44,
        0x19, 0x1E, 0x17, 0x10, 0x05, 0x02, 0x0B, 0x0C,0x21, 0x26, 0x2F, 0x28, 0x3D, 0x3A, 0x33, 0x34,
        0x4E, 0x49, 0x40, 0x47, 0x52, 0x55, 0x5C, 0x5B,0x76, 0x71, 0x78, 0x7F, 0x6A, 0x6D, 0x64, 0x63,
        0x3E, 0x39, 0x30, 0x37, 0x22, 0x25, 0x2C, 0x2B,0x06, 0x01, 0x08, 0x0F, 0x1A, 0x1D, 0x14, 0x13,
        0xAE, 0xA9, 0xA0, 0xA7, 0xB2, 0xB5, 0xBC, 0xBB,0x96, 0x91, 0x98, 0x9F, 0x8A, 0x8D, 0x84, 0x83,
        0xDE, 0xD9, 0xD0, 0xD7, 0xC2, 0xC5, 0xCC, 0xCB, 0xE6, 0xE1, 0xE8, 0xEF, 0xFA, 0xFD, 0xF4, 0xF3 ];


        var crc = initialValue;
        let x: UInt8
    
    for i in 0 ..< buf.count{
            x = crc ^ buf
            crc = Table_CRC8[x]
        }

        return crc;
    }
}
```

I'm dealing with two type errors: *Cannot convert value of type '[UInt8]' to expected argument type 'UInt8'*, and *Cannot convert value of type 'UInt8' to expected argument type 'Int'*. I feel very lost and uncomfortable here.

Basically, this function will be called in a manner as such:

```
var buf : [UInt8] = [0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00];
    buf[0] = 0xAA;
    buf[1] = 0x14;
    buf[2] = ~0x14
    buf[buf.count - 1] = self.calcCR8(buf)
```

Based on this byte array being use a parameter for this example, I'm expecting to get 0xC6 returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few small mistakes.  First, you are trying to perform the xor calculation on `buf` - this is the entire array; You need to access a single element `buf[i]`.

Your second issue is that you can't index a sequence with a `UInt8`, so you need to make an `Int` equivalent in order to access the `Table_CRC8` array.

Finally you are declaring `x` as a `let` (constant) outside the `for` loop, so you can't change it.  You can move the declaration of `x` inside the `for` loop to address this.

Making these small changes will give you code that compiles:

```
for i in 0 ..< buf.count {
    let x = crc ^ buf[i]
    crc = Table_CRC8[Int(x)]
}
```

You can make it more 'Swifty' by changing the name of the CRC table to conform to Swift idioms and use an iteration loop rather than a `for in <range>` loop:

```
func calcCRC8(_ buf : [UInt8]) -> UInt8 {
    let tableCRC8 : [UInt8] = [
        0x00, 0x07, 0x0E, 0x09, 0x1C, 0x1B, 0x12, 0x15,0x38, 0x3F, 0x36, 0x31, 0x24, 0x23, 0x2A, 0x2D,
        0x70, 0x77, 0x7E, 0x79, 0x6C, 0x6B, 0x62, 0x65,0x48, 0x4F, 0x46, 0x41, 0x54, 0x53, 0x5A, 0x5D,
        0xE0, 0xE7, 0xEE, 0xE9, 0xFC, 0xFB, 0xF2, 0xF5, 0xD8, 0xDF, 0xD6, 0xD1, 0xC4, 0xC3, 0xCA, 0xCD,
        0x90, 0x97, 0x9E, 0x99, 0x8C, 0x8B, 0x82, 0x85,0xA8, 0xAF, 0xA6, 0xA1, 0xB4, 0xB3, 0xBA, 0xBD,
        0xC7, 0xC0, 0xC9, 0xCE, 0xDB, 0xDC, 0xD5, 0xD2, 0xFF, 0xF8, 0xF1, 0xF6, 0xE3, 0xE4, 0xED, 0xEA,
        0xB7, 0xB0, 0xB9, 0xBE, 0xAB, 0xAC, 0xA5, 0xA2,0x8F, 0x88, 0x81, 0x86, 0x93, 0x94, 0x9D, 0x9A,
        0x27, 0x20, 0x29, 0x2E, 0x3B, 0x3C, 0x35, 0x32,0x1F, 0x18, 0x11, 0x16, 0x03, 0x04, 0x0D, 0x0A,
        0x57, 0x50, 0x59, 0x5E, 0x4B, 0x4C, 0x45, 0x42,0x6F, 0x68, 0x61, 0x66, 0x73, 0x74, 0x7D, 0x7A,
        0x89, 0x8E, 0x87, 0x80, 0x95, 0x92, 0x9B, 0x9C,0xB1, 0xB6, 0xBF, 0xB8, 0xAD, 0xAA, 0xA3, 0xA4,
        0xF9, 0xFE, 0xF7, 0xF0, 0xE5, 0xE2, 0xEB, 0xEC, 0xC1, 0xC6, 0xCF, 0xC8, 0xDD, 0xDA, 0xD3, 0xD4,
        0x69, 0x6E, 0x67, 0x60, 0x75, 0x72, 0x7B, 0x7C,0x51, 0x56, 0x5F, 0x58, 0x4D, 0x4A, 0x43, 0x44,
        0x19, 0x1E, 0x17, 0x10, 0x05, 0x02, 0x0B, 0x0C,0x21, 0x26, 0x2F, 0x28, 0x3D, 0x3A, 0x33, 0x34,
        0x4E, 0x49, 0x40, 0x47, 0x52, 0x55, 0x5C, 0x5B,0x76, 0x71, 0x78, 0x7F, 0x6A, 0x6D, 0x64, 0x63,
        0x3E, 0x39, 0x30, 0x37, 0x22, 0x25, 0x2C, 0x2B,0x06, 0x01, 0x08, 0x0F, 0x1A, 0x1D, 0x14, 0x13,
        0xAE, 0xA9, 0xA0, 0xA7, 0xB2, 0xB5, 0xBC, 0xBB,0x96, 0x91, 0x98, 0x9F, 0x8A, 0x8D, 0x84, 0x83,
        0xDE, 0xD9, 0xD0, 0xD7, 0xC2, 0xC5, 0xCC, 0xCB, 0xE6, 0xE1, 0xE8, 0xEF, 0xFA, 0xFD, 0xF4, 0xF3 ];
    
    
    var crc = UInt8.min
    
    for byte in buf {
        let x = crc ^ byte
        crc = tableCRC8[Int(x)]
    }
    
    return crc
}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much - this is great! Compiled! My only other question (which is more on how these CRC calculations actually work), is that byte array that gets constructed and put through the calculation is apparently supposed to return 0xC6, which you can see me calling on the `buf[buf.count - 1] = self.calcCR8(buf)` line, but I am simply getting 92 as my CRC result. Even 92 as hexidecimal is 0x5C, which isn't what I'm looking for. Basically just trying to reverse engineer this to match their example byte array. Any insight is more than appreciated, but if not, thanks again for the help :)

Comment: 92 (0x5c) is the correct result for your input data https://crccalc.com/?crc=Aa14eb0000000000%20&method=crc8&datatype=hex&outtype=dec

Comment: or simply return `buf.reduce(.min){tableCRC8[Int($0^$1)]}`